# How can I set state from data in array by using useState?

Tags: reactjs

The code have to set state like:

```
let [dateState, setDateState] = useState({
    mon: true,
    wed: true,
    fri: false
})
```

and I have an array:

```
const arrayData = [mon,wed,fri]
```

I try to use  `setDateState()` inside `forEach()`  but it's still not working. Is any way to set states like the code below?

Comment: Why do you think `setDateState` isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by not working, also can you show how you use setDateState

Comment: Please share more details about what “not working” means.  What is the resulting behavior?

Comment: Do you mean, you've new state data in ``arrayData``

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. hope it helps you. Please **open your console** to see the updated value that is printed.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function UseStateExample() {
    const [dateState, setDateState] = useState({
        mon: false,
        wed: false,
        fri: false
    });

    function clickHandler(e) {
        setDateState({
            ...dateState,
            [e.target.id]: true
        });

        console.log(dateState);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <button id="mon" onClick={clickHandler}>Set Monday</button>
                <button id="wed" onClick={clickHandler}>Set Wednesday</button>
                <button id="fri" onClick={clickHandler}>Set Friday</button>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```